# Couldn't initialize Cloudinary + Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cloudinary

I would like to initialize Cloudinary with Ruby on Rails. But the error occurred when running `rake -t`.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
/config/initializers/cloudinary.rb:2:in `block in <main>'
```

**config/initializers/cloudinary.rb**

```rb
Cloudinary.config do |config|
  config.cloud_name = Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:cloudinary][:cloud_name]
  config.api_key = Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:cloudinary][:api_key]
  config.api_secret = Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:cloudinary][:api_secret]
end
```

I checked, and the correct cloudinary `cloud_name`, `api_key`, and `api_secret` are all set. I usually use s3, but I use Cloudinary to describe images.

Comment: Can you share how you set the secrets (not the actual values)? The `[Rails.env.to_sym]` portion is usually unnecessary in the default setup, see: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#custom-credentials

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Like that. `Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:cloudinary]
=> {:cloud_name=> XXXXXXXXXX, :api_key=> XXXXXXXX, :api_secret=>XXXXXXXXXXXXXX}`